# Month increment query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to update month in my database by adding 1 month but I don't know how I want to add month in my following stored procedure query I am not good in sql kindly check it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePassword] 

@password varchar(20),
@epassword varchar(50),
@username char(32)
AS
UPDATE AccountRole 
    SET Password = @password, 
        EPassword = @epassword 
    WHERE UserName = @username

    UPDATE AccountRole 
    SET ExpiryDate="?"
```

Hhere what do I have to write to increment 1 month when query executes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To increment an existing value of type `DATETIME` or `DATE` by one month, use:

```
UPDATE AccountRole 
SET ExpiryDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ExpiryDate)
```

and as Oleg rightfully pointed out, assuming that your two `UPDATE` statements have the same `WHERE` condition (`WHERE UserName = @username`), then you could do this in a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE dbo.AccountRole 
SET Password = @password, 
    EPassword = @epassword,
    ExpiryDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ExpiryDate)
WHERE UserName = @username
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

```
update AccountRole set ExpiryDate=dateadd(month, 1, ExpiryDate)
where ...
```

Comment: This is a sort of competition between you? 8-D

Answer (score 1):

Try this, *no needs to use second update*:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePassword] 

@password varchar(20),
@epassword varchar(50),
@username char(32)
AS
UPDATE AccountRole 
    SET Password = @password, 
        EPassword = @epassword,
        ExpiryDate=DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()) 
    WHERE UserName = @username
```

Comment: Well, not sure if the second update has a different set of `WHERE` conditions. Only if they are the same, then yes - you're right, everything can be done in single `UPDATE` statement....

Comment: I supposed the common sense 8-)