# Increase value item every week from date / SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a table of horses here.

I have a column which is the age of the horse.

I need the age of each horse to increase by 1 each month after the date of "dob" timestamp.

What is the best practise so in theory each horse ages + 1 per month?

[image: Horse Table]

Comment: To execure Function after perticuler time you can use : Cron Job

Comment: possibly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665389/month-increment-query

Comment: i need an idea how the function would actually work.

Comment: View th post:-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331002/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13416973/6127393

Comment: Why you want to store the data that you can easily derive?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time. (And you've already got product specific answers...)

Answer (score 0):

you could compare DOB column vs current date using DATEDIFF function, by MONTH as interval.

in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE()) AS AGE
...
FROM HORSETABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking consideration of AP suggestion and using Agung Nugroho's answer :

```
UPDATE table 
SET     AGE =  AGE + 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE()) > AGE
```

Need to be adapted after tests (how many "age" for each month difference)